# (Oracle/SQL) Merge all data types into a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, types, merge

Let me explain why I want to do this...  I have built a Tableau dashboard that allows a user to browse/search all of the tables & columns in our warehouse by schema, object type (table,view,materialized view), etc.  I want to add a column that pulls a sample of the data from each column in each table - this is also done, but with this problem...:

The resulting column is comprised of data of different types (varchar2, LONG, etc.).  I can basically get every type of data to conform to a single data type except for LONG - it will not allow me to convert it to anything else compatible with everything else (if that makes sense...).  I simply need all data types to coexist in a single column.  I've tried many different things and have been reading up on the subject for about a week now, but it sounds like it just can't be done, but in my experience there is always a way...  I figured I'd check with the guru's here before admitting defeat.

One of the things I've tried:

```
--Here, from two different tables, I'm pulling a single piece of data from a single column and attempting to merge into a single column called SAMPLE_DATA

--OTHER is LONG data type
--ORGN_NME is VARCHAR2 data type

select 'PLAN','OTHER', cast(substr(OTHER,1,2) as varchar2(4000)) as SAMPLE_DATA from sde.PLAN union all  
select 'BUS_ORGN','ORGN_NME', cast(substr(ORGN_NME,1,2) as varchar2(4000)) as SAMPLE_DATA from sde.BUS_ORGN;
```

Resulting error:

```
Lookup Error
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you looked at this [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:839298816582)?

Comment: Can you hadle CLOBs? If so, you could convert it all to XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long datatypes are basically unusable by most applications.  I made something similar where I wanted to search the contents of packages.  The solution is to convert the LONG into CLOB using a pipelined function.  Adrian Billington's source code can be found here:
https://github.com/oracle-developer/dla

You end up with a view that you can query. I did  not see any performance hit even when looking at large packages so it should work for you.

Comment: In my case, I do not have the ability/authority to create views or install scripts.  I was aiming for an on-the-fly solution.  Something I could run in a query.  Maybe I'm not understanding the solution?

Comment: @Drivium - Probably not on-the-fly.  If you're on 12.1, you might be able to build out a ridiculously complex query with the ability to create PL/SQL objects that have a scope of just the SQL statement.  That would strike me as ludicrously overcomplicated but I think it could be done.

Comment: @drivium If you're going to use that package I'd recommend you take a look at [my fork](https://github.com/jonheller1/dla/commit/3ce1e5501c0c1a8a2fa61cfea308aa867c47ddaf).  It fixes problems with some weird types and column names.  If you're going to query *all* columns, eventually you'll hit one of those weird cases.  What you're trying to do is complicated, it's not realistic to build such a program without any database objects.